# What’s particular about an October kiss?

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

I bumped into this comic strip from long ago, which piqued my interest. Does an *October kiss* constitute something? Is it an autumn tradition, an ancient wizzardry enchantment, an October surprise, or is it just a kiss?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's literary criticism. Specifically, it's prone to reader response theory of interpretation, where an "October kiss" could mean any number of things.

Comment: For the entire strip, see http://peanuts.wikia.com/wiki/October_1970_comic_strips In general there's no special meaning to "an October kiss" as used in the original strip, or in American culture; it's just Snoopy walking around kissing two gals, namely Peppermint Patty (Oct 5) and Lucy (Oct 6). Lucy hates contact with dog saliva, which she equates with rabies. It's an October kiss simply because the strips were originally published in October. Perhaps October (in contrast to, say, February or June) isn't known for being romantic; thus a kiss at the start of autumn night be a nice surprise.

Comment: *might be (typo)

Comment: @Clare Also *Peanuts* usually made somewhat of a fuss over Halloween, with the Great Pumpkin and Linus and all.

Comment: @DanBron True, but notice that the date is pretty early in the month. While it's common to see Halloween stuff in stores these days as soon as the Labor Day sales are over, it wasn't so commercialized in 1970. I doubt he'd do any Halloween-related strips before the last week of the month. I'm with Clare that it just means that the surprise is because there isn't such a thing.

Comment: My favourite Charlie Brown (remembered from my childhood). Lucy : What do you want to be when you grow up ? Charlie Brown (looking straight at the 'camera'  with an expressionless face) : "Perfect".

Comment: The phrase "October kiss" in poetical use in Northern climes where deciduous trees change color denotes a kiss that causes a blush. That's it; that's all there is to it.